# type unicode and type str

Tags: python, unicode

Program written in python 2.6.7!

```
if type(value) == str and 'count(*)' in value:
   testcase['isCountQuery'] = 'true'
   break
```

My test case wont pass because `value` is type `unicode`

```
(Pdb) type(value) == str
False
(Pdb) value
u'select count(*) from uc_etl.agency_1'
(Pdb) type(value)
<type 'unicode'>
(Pdb) value
u'select count(*) from uc_etl.agency_1'
```

I tried changing my if statement to:

```
if type(value) == unicode and 'count(*)' in value:
    testcase['isCountQuery'] = 'true'
    break
```

type == `unicode` does not exists.

I could wrap `str(value)` but I was wondering if there was another fix for this

How can I fix this?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: "*`unicode` does not exists.*" Can you expand on this? What behavior do you see that leads you to that conclusion?

Comment: @Robᵩ this is some flavour of python 2.7, because now in =>3 all strings are unicode and `u'unicodestring'` is deprecated & invalid syntax

Comment: @sysreq - But in 2.7 `unicode` exists while in 3 it doesn't. So we have mixed evidence about what version he is using.

Comment: You're right. I'd hypothesize he's using <2.4/2.3, but I don't know how to test this short of installing it (which I'm not going to do)

Comment: "python 2" isn't specific enough.

Comment: @MarkRansom updated!

Answer (score 3):

At least in python 2 you could check if value is basestring (base class for str and unicode).

```
if isinstance(value, basestring)  and 'count(*)' in value:
   testcase['isCountQuery'] = 'true'
   break
```

Answer (score 3):

[[Python 2.Docs]: Built-in Functions - isinstance(object, classinfo)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) is the preferred way:

```py
from types import StringType, UnicodeType
if value and isinstance(value, (StringType, UnicodeType)) and "count(*)" in value:
    #the rest of the code.
```

Not sure why *unicode* is not defined.